# WorkBox using workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate - cache not updating

Tags: workbox

We have a SPA - Single Page App, loaded via a index.php page and then all interactions / requests are AJAX calls using jQuery 3.2.1.

In our service worker we are using:

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.0.0/workbox-sw.js');

if (workbox) {
    console.log(`Workbox is loaded`);
} else {
    console.log(`Workbox didn't load`);
}

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    // Cache CSS files
    /.*\.js/,
    // Use cache but update in the background ASAP
    workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
        // Use a custom cache name
        cacheName: 'js-cache',
        plugins: [
            new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
                // Only cache requests for a day
                maxAgeSeconds: 1 * 24 * 60 * 60,
                // Only cache 40 requests.
                maxEntries: 40,
            }),
        ]
    })
);
```

This works - loads the files from server and creates the cache:

However never versions of JS files are not picked up - I close the web tab and reload the app and the old version of the JS file is presented to the app.

I expected "staleWhileRevalidate" to fetch the updated JS file in an async request and to update the cache for next time.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Your configuration should, in general, give you the behavior you expect. If you run your web app on `localhost`, extra debugging information will be logged by Workbox in the DevTools console. Do you see anything logged there that's relevant?

Comment: OK I'll try that thanks very much.

Comment: Is your code anywhere on Github or hosted online somewhere? Would make debugging a little easier.

The above should work, although there was a bug that was fixed in v3.1.0 that might fix this problem.